# Double Paging - What does the root/outer page table contain?

Tags: operating-system, paging

I've read three different OS reference books (Stallings, Tanenbaum and Silberschatz) but none of them, from what I've understood, clearly indicates the content type of the outer page in a double paging scheme. In general, the outer page table makes us "find" the inner page table. But does it contain a raw physical address or something else ?

I'm currently following a OS university course, and for an exercise I have to calculate the size (bytes) of an outer page table of 16 elements, the only way I see for an outer page table to make us find an inner page table is to give us a physical address (in this case a physical address is 12 bits long), so I deduct a outer page table is 16*(12+1) bits long (+1 is for validity bit), but the correction states the size is actually 16*(4+1) because the outer page return the number of the page table (I frankly don't know how the number of the page would allow us to retrieve it in any way and I couldn't get a meaningful explanation).

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you are looking for more clearly. What you do you mean by the outer page table? What do you mean by a double paging scheme. The problem is operating systems text books tend to talk in gibberish.

Comment: By double paging scheme I'm talking about a Paging system with two levels, one for the directory (or outer page table), a second for the table page, i.e. a logical address of the form :

REP | PAGE | OFFSET .

The behavior of the two level paging is [as follows](https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=http:%2F%2Fteaching.csse.uwa.edu.au%2Funits%2FCITS2002%2Flectures%2Flecture14%2Fimages%2Ff8.05.png&sp=8627b6375c473daef97f5b509bfe1a2a).

So my question is, does the Root page table contains physical address of page tables or something different ?

Comment: That is system dependent. There are systems where all the page table entries are physical addresses. There are systems where some of the page table entries are physical addresses. There are some systems that divide the address space into user and system where user page tables are logical addresses and the system page tables are physical addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from a university Professor : There is several ways to do it, in my exercise it was proposed that the outer page table would be an "array of array", it's simple to implement but unrealistic as an array of array can be too big to be stored effectively. So a more realistic way to do this is by storing physical address pointers to the inner page tables. As the OS can't predict where these addresses will be stored beforehand, it has to use the system reserved memory that will be fixed in advance (the "low memory", I don't know the correct terminology in English for this), and thus it will be able to use raw physical addresses.